# Can a JIRA plugin work in background without trigger?

Tags: plugins, jira

I was thinking of writing a script/plugin for JIRA that would work in the background to analyze issues raised in JIRA.

Is it possible to write a script/plugin that would work without triggering it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I know that Jira includes the Quartz jar (and presumably uses it under the hood).  It may be possible to leverage its Quartz implementation to schedule a background job.

Answer (score 0):

A JIRA service is a customizable piece of code that runs periodically. That's probably what you want